# Google Document AI does not return textStyle and font information for any document

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-vision, cloud-document-ai

I am using Document AI services to OCR scanned and machine-generated PDF documents. I have tested with 10 different documents but none of them returned with **textStyle** properties (it is always empty).

Just wanted to make sure if that feature is really supported and works or is mentioned in the documentation just to showcase.

**textStyle** information is really critical for our business use-case. So the earliest response will be really appreciated.

I am using default Google python example code

```
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import documentai_v1 as documentai

# TODO(developer): Uncomment these variables before running the sample.
# project_id = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID'
# location = 'YOUR_PROCESSOR_LOCATION' # Format is 'us' or 'eu'
# processor_id = 'YOUR_PROCESSOR_ID' #  Create processor in Cloud Console
# file_path = '/path/to/local/pdf'
# mime_type = 'application/pdf' # Refer to https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list for supported file types


def quickstart(
    project_id: str, location: str, processor_id: str, file_path: str, mime_type: str
):
    # You must set the api_endpoint if you use a location other than 'us', e.g.:
    opts = ClientOptions(api_endpoint=f"{location}-documentai.googleapis.com")

    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=opts)

    # The full resource name of the processor, e.g.:
    # projects/project_id/locations/location/processor/processor_id
    # You must create new processors in the Cloud Console first
    name = client.processor_path(project_id, location, processor_id)

    # Read the file into memory
    with open(file_path, "rb") as image:
        image_content = image.read()

    # Load Binary Data into Document AI RawDocument Object
    raw_document = documentai.RawDocument(content=image_content, mime_type=mime_type)

    # Configure the process request
    request = documentai.ProcessRequest(name=name, raw_document=raw_document)

    result = client.process_document(request=request)

    # For a full list of Document object attributes, please reference this page:
    # https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1.types.Document
    document = result.document

    # Read the text recognition output from the processor
    print("The document contains the following text:")
    print(document.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the `textStyles` attribute is listed as a ["Placeholder"](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Document#:%7E:text=object%20(Style)-,Placeholder,-.%20Styles%20for%20the) in the Documentation, which means it *might* be populated by processors in the future, or it can be used for end user data storage.

You mention

> **`textStyle`** information is really critical for our business use-case.

Could you provide some context of your use case?

Comment: Hold, thank you to get back to me on this.

We are processing Regulatory PDF documents. We apply OCR on these PDF documents and extract text. Then we need to detect some structural information like Headings, Bold Text, Font-size, Bullets, Paragraphs, etc.

So we assumed that Google API will return such information for each line or word. So we can easily identify textStyle information.

I hope you understood the context now and let us know your thoughts that how we can achieve this through Google API.

Comment: Holt, I am sorry for the typo mistake in your name in my previous reply.

Comment: Thank you, could you provide more context on why specifically you need information such as Bold Text and Font Size?

You should be able to access information about Paragraphs/lines/tokens/etc. using the basic text documentation here https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response

If you're looking to get specific information based on the layout, it might make more sense to use the Form Parser or a Specialized Processor.